# Improve mysql range query

Tags: mysql

Is there a better way to do the following:

```
SELECT id FROM main_catalog WHERE release_year <= 2010 AND release_year >= 2000
```

Doing this, it takes about 4s on a table with about 500k records, which seems awful. Here is the `EXPLAIN` statement:

```
id  select_type  table         type    possible_keys   key             key_len     ref   rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE       main_catalog  range   release_year    release_year    3           NULL  365684  Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR
```

Comment: What does the table and keys look like? What indexes are there?

Comment: Are you use you wanted to use `release_year` and `year`?  Should it just use one of them?

Comment: Try changing the conditions to `WHERE release_year  >= 2000 AND release_year <= 2010`

Comment: I think you just have too many entries to return. 365000 in 4s. Also, check the effect of `SET session optimizer_switch='mrr=off'` before executing your query.

Comment: What type of table is this?  InnoDB or MyISAM?  Could you show us the whole table and index definitions?  Also what version of MySQL?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor 365k is a trivial number of rows.

Comment: @David542 Could you show profiling data?  
SET PROFILING=1;  
<your query>;  
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;

Comment: Printing may take 4s :p

Comment: Please provide the DDL for that table and indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your setup on my 2011 Macbook Pro with MySQL 5.6.23 and did not have a performance problem.

```
CREATE TABLE main_catalog (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    release_year int,
    index(release_year)
);

...inserted a whole bunch of rows...

mysql> select count(*) from main_catalog;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   730000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.13 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(id) FROM main_catalog WHERE release_year <= 2010 AND release_year >= 2000;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|    331100 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)

mysql> SELECT id FROM main_catalog WHERE release_year <= 2010 AND release_year >= 2000;
...a whole lot of output...
331100 rows in set (0.15 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT id FROM main_catalog WHERE release_year <= 2010 AND release_year >= 2000;
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | main_catalog | range | release_year  | release_year | 5       | NULL | 364596 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

One possibility is your network connection is slow and having trouble sending the data.  Check if `SELECT COUNT(id)` is equally slow.

You might also try `WHERE release_year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2010` though I don't think it will make a difference.

Comment: @David542 I have updated my answer, I can't replicate your performance problem.

Comment: @David542 So what did it turn out to be?

Comment: I think mostly just the print statement. One of the fields was LONGTEXT and took awhile to print out.